# Символ "+" заменяется на пробел, в базе MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, utf-8, openserver

Есть код, он пост-запросом получает текст:

```
$msg = isset($_POST['usersmsg']) ? $_POST['usersmsg'] : false;
if ($msg) {
   $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO msgs (did,sid,text) VALUES('$did','$sid','$msg')",$db);
```

Все символы корректно добавляются, но не добавляется "+", вместо него в базу записывается пробел.
Кодировка базы utf8_unicode_ci

Пример:

[image: Пример]

Как я понимаю проблема с кодировкой, в мета тэгах стоит

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

При подключении к базе:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема, в какую сторону мне стоит гуглить?

Comment: Кстати, вот так подставлять `$msg` в SQL-код категорически нельзя, потому что получается SQL-инъекция: какой-нибудь хацкер отправит сообщение `'); DELETE from msgs; --` — и плакала ваша база. Почитайте в гугле про экранирование SQL, про mysqli (модуль mysql в PHP давно устарел), про PDO и про плейсхолдеры, чтобы сделать код безопаснее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед отправкой данных на сервер их необходимо кодировать с помощю JS функции *encodeURIComponent()*

Более подробнее [здесь](http://javascript.ru/encodeuricomponent)

Comment: И как же это миллионы форм по всему миру работают безо всякого JavaScript в принципе?

Comment: @PinkTux миллионы форм обрабатываются самим браузером с экранированием как положено, а автор вопроса похоже всё и так через JavaScript делает и косячит

Comment: Как именно делает автор вопроса - нам неизвестно.

Comment: @PinkTux однако, судя по тому, что этот ответ отмечен как лучший, — делает именно так :)

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы, да я делаю через JavaScript. Потому, что данные приходят не с textarea, а с editable div. Возможно, кто-то еще знает, как передавать перенос строки в БД? )

Comment: @Ярик да точно так же по идее

Comment: @PinkTux Если автор отпровляет данные как raw post то кодирование данные по умолчанию не будет происходить. Где читал уже не помню - но это так точно!

Comment: @DanielAbyan,  `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` - это расширение PHP, которое работает на клиентской стороне. И в вопросе явно написано, что работа идёт с `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

Ни MySQL, ни PHP к этому не имеют никакого отношения. Символ "плюс" кодирует пробел в HTTP-запросе. Передавая в POST или GET строку `testing+example` вы фактически передаёте туда строку `testing example`. 
Больше базовых знаний - по запросу "url encoding" в гугле.